# Outlook 2011 to gmail

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2011

We are evaluating moving our business emails from our web server to google apps for business. We have found tools to move all of our mailboxes except the one on Outlook 2011.

I have seen tools like eagle filer which will convert the messages into a manageable format but this mailbox has about a 1000 folders and that is a lot of work when eagle filer will not handle folder hierarchy.

Outlook 2011 only exports to OLM format which appears to be useless and it does not appear to be possible to select multiple folders in 2011 to export with eagle filer the same time.

If I can either convert OLM to PST or get the messages into apple mail with their structure then that would be great otherwise this one mail account may be the scourge of our plans.

Comment: Use IMAP. Don't convert it, export it, or anything like that, because you'll lose important things. @tricasse's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I migrated mailboxes from Outlook 2011 to GMail by adding the GMail account as an IMAP connection in Outlook and drag-and-dropping the folders to the GMail IMAP folders. It requires manual operation for each mailbox (or writing an Outlook macro), but it's free and quite fast, if your Internet connection is good of course.